# Tomcat6 fails accidentally (some times) to deploy the same web app after restart

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, tomcat6, saxparser, cron-task

I receive a strange error messages in logs by restarting my Tomcat6 trought a defined cron job,
which stops my web application to work.

Background: I use Raspbian OS, Java 6, Tomcat 6, JSF API 2.0.1 (jsf-impl2.0.1.jar, jsf-api2.0.1.jar),
            Ajax (throught the embeded Ajax functionallity in JSF 2.0.1), 
            for developing the application i use Windows with Eclipse Indigo, Java 6, JSF2.0, Tomcat 7. The jsf-impl2.0.1.jar and jsf-api2.0.1.jar are placed under `/usr/share/tomcat6/lib` folder.
So, the web application is deployed like a ROOT.war under `/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps`, so i don't use any other apps in my
little web server (Raspberry PI).

So the problem : Normally my web app ***works fine*** - without any error messages in the catalina logs, whithout any other errors and it can work many days so.  I have defined a cron job, which executes every day  a "one commando" script for
restarting my tomcat6 : `sudo service tomcat6 restart`. But sometimes, the restart of my tomcat6 fails to 
deploy my web app war, and fails to start my web app with **everytime different** error messages, but everytime
from the same cause : SAX-Parser errors and they are every time different. So, when i make a SECOND restart manually, 
*immediately after the first restart* from the cron job - the tomcat succeeded and there no problems in logs and my web app
begins to work normally - but the problem is, that i can not make everytime second or third restart of my Tomcat, 
because i can not be every time by my clients.
So, people, any idea, about my case? Please, help! I have researched 5 days, but it is aways not the same case.
If this helps, when i use older jsf-impl and jsf-api,
it works fine, but in this case i can not use the Ajax funcionallity.
Here is the title pieces of my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>a7</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Here is the title pieces of my faces-config.xml:

```
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"  
    version="2.0">
```

Here is the main error, which is aways the same, but with different causes :

```
09-Dec-2014 02:00:49 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of clas
s com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$ParseTask.<init>(ConfigManager.jav
a:810)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.getConfigDocuments(ConfigManager.j
ava:650)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:306)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureLi
stener.java:219)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContex
t.java:4206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4
705)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase
.java:799)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:77
9)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:943)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:778

        .........
```

And hier are for example 3 different causes from SAX-Parser errors, there are aways different:

```
......
Caused by: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseExce
ption; lineNumber: 172; columnNumber: 33; src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name '
xml:lang' to a(n) 'attribute declaration' component.
        at com.sun.faces.config.DbfFactory.initStatics(DbfFactory.java:269)
        at com.sun.faces.config.DbfFactory.<clinit>(DbfFactory.java:186)  

.......
Caused by: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseExce
ption; lineNumber: 56; columnNumber: 7; The element type "xtion" must be termina
ted by the matching end-tag "</xtion>".
        at com.sun.faces.config.DbfFactory.initStatics(DbfFactory.java:269)
        at com.sun.faces.config.DbfFactory.<clinit>(DbfFactory.java:186)  

.......
Caused by: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseExce
ption; lineNumber: 389; columnNumber: 33; Open quote is expected for attribute "
{1}" associated with an  element type  "id".
        at com.sun.faces.config.DbfFactory.initStatics(DbfFactory.java:269)
        at com.sun.faces.config.DbfFactory.<clinit>(DbfFactory.java:186)
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

After months of research and programatical trys, i've found the solution.It is
versions compability issue in combination with `jsp` and `css` syntax errors. For Tomcat6, JSF 1.2 we must use a lower
version of RichFaces Ajax. But is not only that. Take a look of your `jps`'s and `css`'s. The Ajax library has to parse it every time after
Tomcat's restart. Once there is in Tomcat's logs
a syntax SAX parse error for example like:

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 389; columnNumber: 33; Ope
n quote is expected for attribute "{1}" associated with an  element type  "id".
```

And every time the error messages are differnt, like by my case, 
means, that there are parse errors in your .jsp's and .css's.
The solution for my case was to make the right combination between versions
of Tomcat6, JSF1.2 and RichFaces Ajax and to clean my .jsp's and .css's for
syntax errors. Note, that without Ajax, the JSF librarys have no problem
with the parsing of the old source code.

Comment: *After months* cool that you share this here! And you debugged this for months! (BTW: You can accept your own answer if you want: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234)

Comment: Thanks, Rizier123, i preffer, that another people accept my answer. Thanks a lot for your comment.